# Centering an <li> element without taking bullet point into account

Tags: html, css, centering

I am unsure on how to center my `li` elements in the light green space, just based off the green squares I've created around them. As of right now CSS is including the space taken up by the bullet points when centering, which I do not want.

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230);
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 75px;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">End</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried applying `list-style-type: none;` to ul, however this just hides the bullet points, the space they take up is still there.

Comment: most likely the issue is just the margin and/or padding the browser applies to lists as a default.  If you just set `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` to your ul and li styles, you should be able to then align or space it however you prefer.

Comment: 'which I do not want' - bullet points or the space taken, or both?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not actually the *space taken up by the bullet points* - `ul` elements have a default `padding-left` - just reset it to zero:

[image]

Ideally you should just reset the `padding` instead of *negative margins* - see demo below:

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230);
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none; /* hide bullet points */
  padding-left: 0; /* ADDED */
}

li {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 75px;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">End</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Easiest solution to this problem out there. Highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Your given code almost ok just use one single line into style sheet
in li style use below line

```
 list-style-type: none;
```

New li style look like

```
li {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `margin-left` to the `<li>` elemements of `-40px` to offset the `margin` added by the bullet points:

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230);
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">End</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`list-style-type: none` on the `<ul>` is optional.

Comment: This works, thank you. But how did you know margin added by the bullet points was 40px?

Comment: You've identified the root cause (the default padding on the unordered list element) but it might make more sense to just set the padding of the UL to 0 instead of adding the negative margin to the LI.